# How to save PDF files to a SQLite database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, pdf, blob

Can someone give me an example of what the function would be like to read the pdf file and convert it to binary so I can store it in the database.

Comment: @KJ That's (a) not what the OP asked for (b) not necessarily _the best_ (packing data into an SQLite database file can be a good idea for certain apps) (c) a bit misinformed, since the SQLite database file will be in the filesystem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply read the bytes from wherever and put them in a `BLOB` column.

This is one of the "advised" use cases for SQLite too: https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html

```
import pathlib
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")  # could be a real path too
db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pdfs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, data BLOB)"
)

pdf_path = pathlib.Path("./dice_simulator.pdf")
pdf_data = pdf_path.read_bytes()

db.execute("INSERT INTO pdfs (name, data) VALUES (?, ?)", (pdf_path.name, pdf_data))
db.commit()

for name, data, data_length in db.execute("SELECT name, data, LENGTH(data) FROM pdfs"):
    print(f"{name} is {data_length} bytes long")
    assert data == pdf_data
```

Comment: Beautiful, modern, concise, clear Python 

Answer (score -2):

I suggest not to save files in your database.
Instead save file somewhere (for example create folder `pdf` or something like that) and save PATH to file as string in database.
Database actions with big files cost very expensive.

Comment: OP is talking about an SQLite database, which is a file anyway.

Comment: @AKX what do you mean? Each database is file or bunch of files anyway.